# How to draw Isometric game Back to front

Tags: java, rendering, isometric

What is the for loop or algorytm for a 2D array of tiles that I would render the tiles back to front like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the opposite of how you would draw them front to back.

Comment: The opposite of that is http://pastebin.com/86WvUdBs You just have to decrement instead of increment.

Comment: NVM figured it out.